# What is the meaning of 提提大家？

Tags: meaning-in-context, cantonese, colloquialisms

What is the meaning and usage of 提提大家？please give an example sentence or phrase.

I have seen that the meaning of 提提 is to keep calm, but putting these two in google translate gives me “mention everyone”.

Comment: You tagged `Cantonese` in this question. Google translate doesn't have a option to translate from Cantonese.

Comment: I used google translate thinking that the translation might be similar to standard chinese, and assuming that this is not a colloquial phrase or slang.

Comment: Native Chinese here(though I don't like China, it's personal), and I have never in my life seen or heard such a strange expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question's answer will address two things.

1. the advantage of compound words (specific) over the single character words (general)
2. the function of the reduplicated verbs

提 as a single character verb can mean:

- 提起，提及 (mention)
- 提醒 (remind)
- 提示 (prompt)
- 提起 (lift; pick up)

Example:

別再**提**他了 = 別再**提起**他了 (Let's don't **mention** him again)

記得**提**他吃藥 = 記得**提醒**他吃藥 (remember to **remind** him to take medicine)

別**提**他，讓他自己想 = 別**提示**他，讓他自己想 (don't **prompt** him, let him think for himself)

**提**刀斬人 = **提起**刀斬人 (**pick up** a blade and hack people)

It would be much more precise to use compound words 提起，提醒 and 提示 than using the single character verb 提.

A single character verb can be reduplicated to indicate 'briefly; in a slight degree or in a casual manner'

Example:

試學廣東話 = try to learn Cantonese

試試學廣東話 = try to learn Cantonese a little (briefly; in a slight degree or in a casual manner)

看電影，吃飯 = watch movies, eat dinner

看看電影， 吃吃飯 = watch some movies, eat some  dinner (indicate a casual manner)

> 提提大家 = (slightly; briefly) remind everyone

> Example sentence:

> 提提大家，集會時間是晚上九時 = (slightly; briefly) remind everyone, the gathering time is 9:00 pm

> It is the same as 稍為提醒大家，集會時間是晚上九時

Comment: thank you for the very substantial explanation. I just would like to point out that there is a very similar structure or nuance in colloquial Filipino. When you repeat some verbs, the idea becomes very casual, brief, indicating a slight manner. This is very fun to know that this idea also exists in canto.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean to remind everyone.  For example, 請提提大家食飯 would mean to remind everyone to eat a meal.